# Sum equal adjacent integers

Tags: clojure

Test case:

```clj
(def coll [1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5])

(def p-coll (partition 2 1 coll))

;; ((1 2) (2 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 4) (4 4) (4 5))
```

Expected output:

`(2 2 4 4 4) => 16`

Here is what I am to implement: Start with vector `v [0]`. Take each pair, if the first element of the pair is equal to the last element of the vector, or if the elements of the pair are equal, add the first item of the pair to `v`. (And finally reduce `v` to its sum.) The code below can do *if the elements of the pair are equal* part, but not the first part. (Thus I get `(0 2 4 4)`. I guess the reason is that the elements are added to `v` at the very end. My questions:

1. What is the way to compare an element with the last selected element?
2. What other idiomatic ways are there to implement what I am trying achieve?
3. How else can I approach the problem?

```clj
(let [s [0]]
  (concat s (map #(first %)
                 (filter #(or (= (first %) (first s)) (= (first %) (second %))) p-coll))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with partitioning the data here.  But there
is a nicer way to do that.  You can use `(partition-by identity coll)`
to group consecutive, same elements.

Then just keep the ones with more than one elements and sum them all up.
E.g.

```
(reduce 
  (fn [acc xs] 
    (+ acc (apply + xs))) 
  0 
  (filter 
    next 
    (partition-by identity coll)))
```

Comment: You could probably streamline this with transducers, something like `(transduce (comp (partition-by identity) (filter next) (map (partial apply +))) + 0 coll)`

Comment: @Rulle `cat` comes in handy here, making this `(transduce (comp (partition-by identity) (filter next) cat) + coll)`.  We also don't need 0 because `(+)` evals to 0.

Comment: @jaihindhreddy Using `cat` is an elegant improvement!

Comment: @jaihindhreddy @Rulle Can someone please explain how `filter next` works?

Comment: @blackened Try `(next [1 2 3])` and `(next [1])` in your REPL.

Comment: @blackened `next` is a function that returns a sequence with all but the first thing in the input sequence if there are any, and `nil` otherwise. Truthiness in Clojure is quite simple, `false` and `nil` are falsy, and everything else is truthy. These two facts combine to make `next` a valid predicate to check that there are at least 2 things in a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Starting out from your initial partition, with `p-coll` being like you described above (i.e. a list of pairs), and v being the vector `[0]`, you can do the following:

```
(reduce 
  (fn [vect [a b]] 
    (if (or (= a b) (= a (last vect))) 
      (conj vect a) 
      vect)) 
  v p-coll)

;; => [0 2 2 4 4 4]
```

We start from the vector `[0]`, and reduce `p-coll` by processing its elements one by one. If an element satisfies one of the two conditions you specified, then we `conj` it onto the initial vector. Otherwise, we leave the vector as is.

Finally, you can use `apply +` to sum the resulting vector and get your final answer.

Generally, when you need to process a collection (here, `p-coll`) and some partial answer (here, the vector `v`) into some sort of final answer (here, the vector `[0 2 2 4 4 4]`), `reduce` is the most idiomatic and purely functional approach. After having identified those components, it's just a matter of coming up with the appropriate function to put them together.

Another approach (less idiomatic, but easier to understand from a procedural standpoint) would be to use an atom for the vector `v`, and keep growing it as you process the list with `doseq`:

```
(def v (atom [0]))

(doseq [[a b] p-coll]
  (if (or (= a b) (= a (last @v)))
    (swap! v conj a)))

(println @v)
;; => [0 2 2 4 4 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (Shouldn't `v` be `[0]` in your first code?) I am a Clojure newbie, so please excuse this question: The part `fn [vec [a b]]` confuses me. What exactly does it say? Had it been something like `fn [a b] ...` I would know that the anonymous function will do something with two arguments. What does it say here? That there are two arguments, and the second one is a `vector` with two elements? (That cannot be, because `p-coll` will be there.)

Comment: I was assuming you'd have bound `v` to `[0]` beforehand, but yes you're right - could be either. As for the `fn [vec [a b]]` part, what it's saying is that the function expects two arguments: a vector (the partial result that we're building) and a pair of two elements - call the first element of the pair `a`, and the second one `b`. Since we are processing `p-coll` one element at a time, and its elements are pairs, we can specify the "structure" of the expected arguments in our function's parameter list. This is called destructuring, if you'd like to read further on it.

Comment: I am aware of that much destructuring; what confuses me is how does it know that we are processing `p-coll` one element at a time? Because of `reduce`?

Comment: Yes it's basically because of `reduce`... `reduce` will process `p-coll` one element at a time as it's building the final answer, so the function we give it as an argument needs to take in only one element.

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution only with `flatten` and `map`:

```
(defn consecutives [lst]
  (flatten (map (fn [[x y z]] (cond (= x y z) [z] 
                                    (= y z) [y z]
                                    :else []))
                (map #'vector lst (rest lst) (rest (rest lst))))))
```

#### Purely tail-recursive solution

which "keeps in memory" previous and previous-previous element.

```
(defn consecutives 
  [lst]
  (loop [lst lst
         acc []
         last-val nil
         last-last-val nil]
    (cond (empty? lst) acc
          :else (recur (rest lst) 
                       (if (= (first lst) last-val)
                           (conj (if (= last-val last-last-val)
                                     acc
                                     (conj acc last-val)) 
                                 (first lst))
                           acc)
                       (first lst) 
                       last-val))))
(consecutives coll)
;; => [2 2 4 4 4]
```